# Могут ли комиты в системе контроля версий быть доказательством авторских прав на код?

Tags: git, авторские-права

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Может ли это быть доказательством авторства кода в суде и досудебном разбирательстве?

Comment: Не могут, потому что кто угодно может создать какой угодно коммит

Comment: PGP-подпись потенциально может служить доказательством авторства коммита, однако это совсем не значит, что автор коммита является автором кода

Comment: Зарегистрируйте ПО в Федеральной службе по Интеллектуальной Собственности.

Comment: Чужое ПО сложно зарегистрировать

Comment: *"Учётная запись временно заблокирована с целью дать участнику успокоиться. Срок действия блокировки истечёт 14 фев **2025** в 19:49."* --- эх, кажется я пропустил драму))

Comment: То-то я чувствую, что за знакомые нотки во всех вопросах...... а это @Грузчик вернулся     Который тоже кучу некачественного контента приваливал и которого тоже блочили..... Время идёт, ничего не меняется.... только ник 

Answer (score 1):

Не могут.
Авторское право, как и патент, должно быть зарегистрировано в соответствии с законодательством.
Стоит также обратить внимание на то, что некоторые виды интеллектуальной собственности могут регистрироваться как на территории определенной страны, так и на территории нескольких стран.
Рекомендую посмотреть видео обзоры, прочитать статьи от компаний, занимающихся патентами и авторскими правами, а также изучить законодательство в данной области, действующее на территории нужной Вам страны. Также важно понимать отличии авторского права от патента, каким образом можно передавать право на использование и прочие моменты.
Я только недавно начала интересоваться данными вопросами, поэтому пока не могу подсказать деталей, но, надеюсь, что ответ был хоть как-то полезен.